# How can I easily revert a starter deck to its original state?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-master-duel

In Yu-Gi-Oh! Master Duel, after the tutorial, you are to choose between three starter decks: Power of Dragons (classic gameplay), Synchro of Unity (synchro focused gameplay), Link Generator (link focused gameplay)

I have chosen Power of Dragons and used it to climb out of Bronze, and tweaked it a lot with crafted cards and opened secret pack cards

I would like to invite some friends to play the game and fight them with the OG Power of Dragons deck

Is there a way to easily revert the deck back to its state when I first got it, or do I have to search what the deck consisted of and remove what wasn't in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have master copies of all structure decks available (including the starter decks).
If you go to *Deck* you can find a button *List of Structure Decks* in the bottom right. Clicking on it brings you to the list of the structure decks.
You can click on one of the decks and then on *Copy Deck* to create a new copy of this deck in your normal deck list.
[image]
[image]
[image]